# Как убрать отступы блока в html, все перепробовал, не понимаю?

Tags: html, css

Учусь верстать сайты. Да, не самое лучшее, но почему бы и нет. Получается копировать сайты, большинство в коде понимаю, что за что отвечает, но в своем не могу понять, откуда появились эти отступы. Помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Вы забываете, что у таких элементов, как `<p>`, `<h1>` и т.п., есть стили по умолчанию. Подключайте **[reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** или контролируйте вручную все отступы:

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.body>div { padding-left: 20px; }
.shapka { background: #547BA3; }
.seredina { background-color: #EFF1F3; }
.osnova { background-color: #EFd1d3; }

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0.67em 0;
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <div class="shapka">
    <h1>Первый блок</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="seredina">
    <h1>Второй блок</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="osnova">
    <h1>Третий блок</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: А как это сделать подробнее? Я посмотрел в интернете, reset.css и там написано, что это сброс настроек стилей, но как это сделать? Заново переписать?

Comment: @ТоликГолощапов, просто в теге `<head>` подключите этот файл самым первым, т.е. до подключения остальных стилей.

Comment: Он у меня через link подключен, через head сделал, но не работает. (Сам style файл работает. Слева, справа убрал, а сверху и снизу не робит)